# Numpy: slicing a 3D array from a 4D array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

Say if I have a 4D numpy array of dimensions: 10 x 10 x 10 x 10, and I want to obtain 3D subset based on some indexes I know (e.g. ([1,2],0,[5,6],[9,0]). How do I go about doing this, and what should I do if my indices aren't sequential, like in my example?

For instance, if I try doing this:

```
test[0:2, 0, 3:5, 0:2]
```

I get a 2 x 2 x 2 array as expected. However, if I try explicitly defining each dimension value like so:

```
test[[0,1], 0, [3,4], [0,1]]
```

I instead obtain a 2 x 1 array. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is between basic indexing and advanced.  Indexing with slices and scalars is 'basic'.  When one or more of the indexes are lists or array, it uses 'advanced'.
[Docs on advanced v basic indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

There are various ways of producing the kind of indexing that you want. `np.ix_` is designed to make this easy:

```
In [80]: np.ix_([0,1], [0], [3,4], [0,1])
Out[80]: 
(array([[[[0]]],


        [[[1]]]]), array([[[[0]]]]), array([[[[3],
          [4]]]]), array([[[[0, 1]]]]))

In [79]: arr[np.ix_([0,1], [0], [3,4], [0,1])].shape
Out[79]: (2, 1, 2, 2)
```

To pass all indices through `ix_` I had to make the 2nd one a list.  A way around that is to use `ix_` on just 3 lists, and add that `0` later:

```
In [81]: I,J,K=np.ix_([0,1], [3,4], [0,1])
In [82]: arr[I,i,J,K].shape
Out[82]: (2, 2, 2)
In [83]: I,J,K
Out[83]: 
(array([[[0]],

        [[1]]]), array([[[3],
         [4]]]), array([[[0, 1]]]))
```

Note the shape of the index arrays:

```
In [84]: I.shape
Out[84]: (2, 1, 1)
In [85]: J.shape
Out[85]: (1, 2, 1)
In [86]: K.shape
Out[86]: (1, 1, 2)
```

together they broadcast to a (2,2,2) shape.  So any index arrays that broadcast that way should work.  You could make `J` with

```
In [87]: J
Out[87]: 
array([[[3],
        [4]]])
In [88]: np.array([3,4])[None,:,None]
Out[88]: 
array([[[3],
        [4]]])
```

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for the clear and concise answer!